# check satisfiability of a constraint when using rails shovel operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

In my rails application, I have a group class which has a many to many relation with itself. The relation in question is "having subgroups."

```
class Group
    has_and_belongs_to_many :subgroups, class_name: 'Group'
    ...
end
```

I am using shovel operator to add a collection of groups (as subgroups) to an specific group X. The constraint in this question is that we should not have any cycles formed when adding subgroups, i.e. I have to make sure that none of the new members are already an ancestor of group X.

One straight answer is to write a custom method to do this, which surely is possible but I'd like to know if it is possible to have this achieved using the shovel operator and not a custom function of my own.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to achieve this behaviour with the shovel operator. The good news is, since the association "ducks" like an array, you can use the union operator along with `Array()` to convert the input, e.g.

```
> group_a, group_b = Group.new, Group.new
> group_a.subgroups |= Array(group_b)
```